# arbaic not suport Dompdf in php project

Tags: php, dompdf

hi guys i am using Dompdf in php project  but persian not support and rander '?' Instead of persian words.

I do not know what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same problem as you before and there is a lack of recourses when it comes to Arabic and Persian languages but I found this library which is great for pdf manipulation

its called TCPDF
: [enter link description here](https://tcpdf.org/)

Arabic and Persian example:https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_018/ 
I hope it solves your problem

Comment: thanks bro I was really in trouble